# SSL protocol on AWS architecture?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services

Here's my AWS architecture

```
1 Load Balancer
2 Web/Application server
1 DB server
```

If client - and my LB communicates with SSL(HTTPS) protocol,
would it be safe with internal LB-WEB/APP-DB server communicates with HTTP? Or should they communicate with same SSL certificates internally too?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can terminate SSL on your web instances, but it is probably much easier to have SSL on your load balancer, and communicate over http between ELB and web instance.

This assumes you're running inside of a VPC of course.

Comment: Thank you, but I think creating ELB and connecting EC2s into it makes VPC automatically. Is it right? I'm new in AWS and first-timer deploying multiple servers

Comment: @sungpi: You can run ELB and your instances outside a VPC - having a load balancer doesn't automatically mean you're inside of one.

Comment: I didn't touch anything about VPC, but as soon as I found your comment, and I found that VPC environment exist for my LB and EC2 instances. (?) I'm bit confused. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As you scale having SSL terminated at your LB and internal traffic non-SSL will save you a great deal of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cloudfront
Another option is to create a Cloudfront distribution in-front of your ELB, where your SSL connection is terminated at the nearest Edge Location. From Cloudfront to LLB(In a particular region) it uses AWS WAN so if you can live with that level of security, you can get better performance also with static content cached and delivered from Edge location. Another advantage is that you can get free SSL certificates from AWS for Cloudfront regardless of your ELB region.

For the DB Server, normally it kept inside the same VPN as the WebServer and not allowed for external access. So I don't see a great deal in putting a separate certificate for DB access within the private network unless you have specific regulatory requirements.